# Meaning of "ça ne va pas comme ça"

Tags: expressions, traduction

I just want to know what is the meaning of "ça ne va pas comme ça" or "ça va pas comme ça". I thought it does mean "it doesn't work that way" just like "ça marche pas comme ça" or something like that. I can't find any related result on Google. I'm asking this question because Ive used this phrase 1000 times when I was in France.

Comment: Another option: It's not working out the way you're doing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my point of view, *"comme ça"* designates **the way a specific thing is happening**.

I would use the sentence *"ça ne va pas comme ça"* to emphasize the fact that I don't agree with the way itself (*"comme ça"*).

Let's make an example:

> "Maman, je peux mélanger le beurre avec la farine ?"
>
> "Bien sûr, montre-moi comment tu fais."
>
> [...]
>
> "Non, ça ne va pas comme ça ! Prends la cuillère avec ta main droite et fais des tours plus rapides, comme ça."
>
> *elle lui montre le bon geste *

A clearer (maybe) way of phrase it could be : *"Comme ça, ça ne va pas"*, where the coma separates better the two parts of the sentence.

Comment: are you french?

Comment: Yes I am French. :)

Comment: My pleasure, have a nice weekend. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think best translation would be : "It's not correct that way"